# Javascript redirect with effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Can I make redirect to the same page only with JS and without Jquery? 
Because I have a problem that sounds like this: 
In my page I use bxslider and it has own jquery link. So, if I add both links(google jquery CDN and bxslider) then neither smooth redirect works nor the bxslider. 
Any solutions?

Comment: Including some code would make it easier to help. You should be able share one import of jquery between bxslider and your own code. If you want to use jquery for your redirect, there's no reason it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

reloads/refreshes the page

```
function myFunction() {
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: I think, you didn't understand question fully. 
I have done that you have said, but I am talking about the redirecting with effect i.e. like here http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/ but just without the jquery